# I can't seem to understand why my updateById route doesn't work on Android Studio

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, rest, put

I'm programming a password manager app with a MySql database and a spring boot back-end.

My routes on the spring boot back-end work perfectly and I tested them with postman. Most of them also work in my android studio app with the help of retrofit. But the last one that I need is updateAccountById() with a Put request.
This Put route works with postman but won't work in my android studio app and I can't seem to find why.

This is my repository methods in the spring-boot back-end (There is an @Service with the class but stackoverflow doesn't like it) :

```
public class AccountDao {
@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

/** Create new account **/
public Account save(Account account){
    return accountRepository.save(account);
}

/** Delete account **/
public void deleteById(int id){
    accountRepository.deleteById(id);
}

/** Get all accounts **/
public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    Streamable.of(accountRepository.findAll()).get().forEach(accounts::add);

    return accounts;
}

/** Get accounts by category **/
public List<Account> getAccountsByCategory(int id){
    List<Account> accountsByCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    Streamable.of(accountRepository.findAll()).get().filter(account -> account.getCategoryId() == id).forEach(accountsByCategory::add);

    return accountsByCategory;
}

/** Get account by id **/
public Account getAccountById(int id){
    return accountRepository.findById(id).get();
}

/** Get favorites accounts **/
public List<Account> getFavoriteAccounts(){
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    Streamable.of(accountRepository.findAll()).get().filter(Account::getFavorite).forEach(accounts::add);
    return accounts;
}
```

}

Then this is my rest-api routes in my controller (There is an @Restcontroller) :

```
public class Controller {

/** DAO initialization **/
@Autowired
CategoryDao categoryDao = new CategoryDao();

@Autowired
AccountDao accountDao = new AccountDao();


/** REST routes **/


/** Categories routes **/
/* Get one category by id */
@GetMapping("/category/{id}")
public Category getCategoryById(@PathVariable int id) {
    return categoryDao.getCategoryById(id);
}


/* Get all categories route */
@GetMapping("/categories")
public List<Category> getCategories(){
    return categoryDao.getAllCategory();
}

/* Create a new category */
@PostMapping("/category/save")
public Category newCategory(@RequestBody Category category){
    return categoryDao.save(category);
}

/* Delete a category */
@DeleteMapping("/category/delete/{categoryId}")
public void delCategory(@PathVariable int categoryId){
    categoryDao.deleteById(categoryId);
}


/** Accounts routes **/

/* Get accounts by category */
@GetMapping("accounts/{categoryId}")
public List<Account> getCategory(@PathVariable int categoryId){
    return accountDao.getAccountsByCategory(categoryId);
}

/* Get one account by ID */
@GetMapping("/account/{accountId}")
public Account getAccount(@PathVariable int accountId){
    return accountDao.getAccountById(accountId);
}

@GetMapping("accounts/favorite")
public List<Account> favorites(){
    return accountDao.getFavoriteAccounts();
}

/* Create new account */
@PostMapping("/account/save")
public Account newAccount(@RequestBody Account account){
    return accountDao.save(account);
}

/* Edit an account */
@PutMapping("/update/{accountId}")
public ResponseEntity<Account> updateAccount(@PathVariable int accountId, @RequestBody Account accountDetails){
    Account account = accountDao.getAccountById(accountId);
    account.setCategoryId(accountDetails.getCategoryId());
    account.setName(accountDetails.getName());
    account.setUserName(accountDetails.getUserName());
    account.setPassword(accountDetails.getPassword());
    account.setUrl(accountDetails.getUrl());
    account.setFavorite(accountDetails.getFavorite());

    Account updateAccount = accountDao.save(account);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(updateAccount);
}



/* Delete an Account */
@DeleteMapping("/account/delete/{accountId}")
public void delAccount(@PathVariable int accountId){
    accountDao.deleteById(accountId);
}
```

}

Finally, this is my retrofit routes on Android Studio with the way I use it :

```
public interface AccountApi {

@GET("/account/{categoryId}")
Call<Account> getAccount(@Path("categoryId") int id);

@GET("/accounts/{categoryId}")
Call<List<Account>> getAccountsByCategory(@Path("categoryId") int id);

@GET("/accounts/favorite")
Call<List<Account>> getFavoriteAccounts();

@POST("/account/save")
Call<Account> saveAccount(@Body Account account);

@PUT("/update/{accountId}")
Call<Account> updateAccount(@Path("accountId") int id, @Body Account account);

@DELETE("/account/delete/{id}")
Call<ResponseBody> deleteAccount(@Path("id") int id);
```

}

This is in an OnClickListener :

```
 accountApi.getAccount(getArguments().getInt("accountID")).enqueue(new Callback<Account>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Account> call, Response<Account> response) {
            edit_name.setText(response.body().getName());
            edit_username.setText(response.body().getUserName());
            edit_password.setText(response.body().getPassword());
            edit_url.setText(response.body().getUrl());
            edit_favorite.setChecked(response.body().getFavorite());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Account> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```